Is a ring where all elements are periodic necessarily reduced?
Let $R$ be a ring. An element $a\in R$ is said to be periodic if there exist positive integers $m \neq n$ such that $a^n=a^m$. If $m=1$ then we say that $a$ is $n$-potent.
Following the answer to this question, we call "$n$-ring" a ring in which each element is $n$-potent. It is shown there that these rings are reduced (i.e. no non zero nilpotent is present).
My question is, if we call "periodic rings" rings where each element is periodic, are these rings reduced?
My attempt to prove reducedness, let $a^n=0$. Since $a$ is periodic it means $a^k=a^s$. Now $n$ cannot be less than $k,s$. If $n>k,s$ then how to proceed?

What does "We have $n$ rings where each element is $n$-potent" mean? Whatever it does mean to "have $n$ rings", would not each of these be an example for the weaker property you are asking about (as every $n$-potent element is periodic)?

Please do not answer in the comments, @Muhammad.

@TorstenSchoeneberg We have n rings but I want periodic rings which are not n rings means strictly larger class, that's why I say that n-rings are reduced, so are periodic rings reduced also?

Let me try to understand you: 1) You call an "$n$-ring" a ring in which every element is $n$-potent, correct? 2) You are saying that every $n$-ring is reduced, correct? 3) You are asking whether in the more general class of rings where every element is periodic, there are non-reduced rings, correct?

Yes @TorstenSchoeneberg in more general class where some elements are non-potents but every element is periodic.

@Chaudhary: I edited the question to make it clearer what you (presumably) are asking. You should have done that.

$\mathbb{Z_n}$ is not reduced whenever $n$ is not square free natural number, but it is finite and hence periodic.

This does not attempt to answer the question. At best it is a comment only.

@amWhy , yesterday I add this as a comment but Shaun deleted the comment by saying please do not answer in the comments.

I think this is a perfectly valid answer to the question as it stands / was clarified in comments, giving an easy counterexample.
